# Reload PartialView from jQuery in ASP.NET MVC 2 application?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to use jQuery to load a PartialView. It does this fine at the first loading of the page. But then I need to be able to reload the PartialView when a save button is pressed. I get a reload, but this time the PartialView is all I get back. I.e. I don't get the PartialView loaded as a part of the main page, but rather as a page of its own. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the relevant parts of the jQuery in the View:

```
       $.get('<%=Url.Action("GetTasks", "Timesheet", new {id = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() }) %>', function (data) {
            $('#tasksDiv').html(data);
        }); //This part works fine on first load of the page

        $('#savenewtask').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.get('<%=Url.Action("GetTasks", "Timesheet", new {id = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() }) %>', function (data) {
                $('#tasksDiv').html(data);
            });
        }); //This only loads the PartialView, but not as part of the main page...
```

The button and the div to load in:

```
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Spara" id="savenewtask" />
    </p>

<div id="tasksDiv">
</div>
```

UPDATE:

It actually worked, I had just confused the two input fields I have on the page. But I'll rephrase the question to a simple one: Is this the best way to do this sort of thing with PartialViews, or should I go about it another way? (I.e. I was just trying to figure out a way to achieve what I wanted without knowing if it is the "best practice" way of doing it).

Comment: Does "#tasksDiv" appear more than once on the page? I want to help you buy you don't accept answers...

Comment: See update above. Really? I think I try to accept answers as much as possible. Of course sometimes I don't get any useful answers to some questions, and then there isn't much to do, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have typically used the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, which sets the innerHtml.

```
var url = '<%=Url.Action("GetTasks", "Timesheet", new {id = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() }) %>'
$("#tasksDiv").load(url);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I had confused the two input fields. It actually works fine. However, I'll rephrase my question and accept the answer for that instead. See update above.

Comment: I always go for the path of least resistance `.load()` provides that. There is no need for a delegate/callback and the syntax reads more clearly. "Take this div, and load the content of this url into it." There is nothing wrong with doing a get+callback; I just found it to require more code; however, there may be instances where it is necessary over a simple `.load()` call, say if you wanted to process the return value before you display it...